# Command Prompt vs passing command arguments through debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am doing a homework assignment, and when I go under the projects properties page, go to debugging, and use the command arguments the program works. If i try to use the command prompt with the appropriate inputs it does not work and throws an exception at me.

```
void byName(char *name) {

    read();
    element_t *e = top;
    while (strcmp(e->name, name) != 0) {//throws an exception
        e = e->next;
    }
    if (e == NULL) {
        printf("Error: element not found");
    }
    else {
        list(e);
    }

}
```

I don't understand how it can run through visual studios and not throw an exception, while at the same time fail to run through command prompt. It should either throw an exception both ways, or not through an exception either way, right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also include how you run it from the command prompt and what arguments you set in Visual Studio for it

Comment: You should also show the code in `main()` that calls `byName()`, and any prior argument processing code.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
while (strcmp(e->name, name) != 0) {//throws an exception
    e = e->next;
}
```

you go on forever in case `name` doesn't match any element in the list. Therefore you'll reach the end of the list and use `e` when it has the value NULL.

Change the loop so it stops if `e` becomes NULL. Like:

```
while (e != NULL && strcmp(e->name, name) != 0) {//throws an exception
    e = e->next;
}
```